# if $f([a,b])=[c,d]$ and $[c,d] \subset [a,b]$, is there $x \in [c,d]$ such that $f(x)=x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I'm trying to prove something that I'm not sure is correct.

Let $f$ be a continuous, differentiable and monotonic function $f:[a,b] \to [c,d]$, where $[c,d] \subset [a,b]$.

Is there an $x \in [c,d]$ such that $f(x)=x$?

Comment: Try considering $g(x)=f(x)-x$ on $[c,d]$. Then use the Intermediate Value Theorem to show that $\exists c$ such that $g(c)=0$.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you, that is correct. Please write an answer, so I may accept and close this question.

Comment: Fixed, thanks Daniel. Someone will probably beat me to it, working on the details of a proof.

Comment: Is the theorem sharp? Suppose $f$ is not monotonic, simply $C^1$ on $[a,b]$, and still $f([a,b])=[c,d]$ , $[c,d] \subset [a,b]$. Is there still a fixed point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, consider $g(c)=f(c)-c$. $g(c)\ge 0$ is obviously true because $f([c,d])\to[c,d]$.

If $g(c)=0$ then we have our $x$ and we're done.

So, now let's consider $g(c)>0$ and the value of $g(d)$.

Through a similar argument as used for $g(c)\geq 0$, we have $g(d)\leq 0$.

Again, if $g(d)=0$ we're done.

So we have the three cases $g(c)=0$, $g(d)=0$, or $g(c)>0$ and $g(d)<0$.

In the last case, if $g(x)$ is continuous (which it is if $f(x)$ is), we use the Intermediate Value Theorem to prove existance of $\alpha\in[c,d]$ such that $g(\alpha)=0$.

So, as long as $f(x)$ is continuous and $f([c,d])\to[c,d]$, we have shown $\exists \alpha\in[c,d]$ such that $f(\alpha)=\alpha$.

It's been a while since I've done real analysis so I hope I haven't made any mistakes.

Comment: Only 'mistake' I could find is that $e$ is a very poor letter to choose when you want to give something a name :) But yeah, thank you. I noticed you did not use that $f$ is monotonic. I guess it is not needed.

Comment: Ok, $\alpha$ it is then, I guess it is a special enough value to warrant using Greek. And yeah, it's not necessary, neither is the restriction to the range $[c,d]$, $f:[a,b]\to[a,b]$ would work as well.